# multiples imagenes en pdf usando itext 7 C#

Tags: c#

Me he leido la documentacion y no entiendo bien como hacerlo
este es el codigo que tengo, copia es un arreglo que tiene los path de las imagenes, tampoco se como crear el pdf en CMYK

```
        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("D:\\tmp\\demo.pdf");
         PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
         Document document = new Document(pdf);

          for (int i = 0;i < copia.Length;i++)
          {
             iText.Layout.Element.Image img = new 
             iText.Layout.Element.Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(copia[i]));
             document.Add(img);
          }

           document.Close();
        }
`
```